# Complete two-period model with specific replication strategy

Tags: options, asset-pricing, replication

> Find a complete two-period model in which the unique replication
> strategy of a call (with a suitably chosen strike) shorts the stock in
> the first period (i.e. the call price falls if the stock rises in the
> first period). However, there is no such example with a negative
> replication strategy in the second period. Why?

I tried constructing to see where it fails, but I am struggling to find the issue. Could someone help me?